# Python : Clicking first google result using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, search, findelement

I've tried almost every method of trying to click on the first result of google search.
I was trying to find the element using almost every queue i've found on the net, unfurntantlly no one of them succeed.
Please is there anyone who think he knows how can i click on it or even just getting the href as a text and i'll nevigate there by myself ...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I've tried almost every method of trying to click on the first result of google search - Please show us the code what you've tried so far. We need to see in the code where you did go wrong.

Comment: Try an xpath something like: "//div[@class='g']/div/div/div/a"